# Pointers in LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am studying the linked lists,and I'm having a little problem understanding references and pointers in Java (and also have some questions for which I can't find answer on the internet.) Namely,I have a class `LinkedList` that uses class `Node` like this:

```
public class LinkedList {
    public Node head;
    public LinkedList(int data) {
        head = new Node(data);
    }
}
```

and this is my Node class:

```
public class Node {
    public int data;
    public Node next;
    public Node(int data2) {
        data = data2;
    }
}
```

I also have method `toStringLL()` inside `LinkedList` which looks like:

```
public void toStringLL() {
    LinkedList l=this;
    while(l.head.next != null) {
        System.out.print(l.head.data+"->");
        l.head = l.head.next;
    }
    System.out.print(l.head.data);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I don't understand why this `toStringLL()` changes my head of linked list,when I am iterating through it with `l.head=l.head.next`? Shouldn't my head stay the same?I thought that when I write `LinkedList l=this`,I can freely iterate through `l`,without affecting `this`(or am I wrong?) Now when I use `Node n=this.head` instead of `LinkedList l=this`,it works,but I have difficulty figuring out why that works and the previous doesn't.. Can someone explain to me the difference between these two?

Comment: Java has no pointers.

Comment: When you do `LinkedList l = this;` you are **not** making a copy of the list, you are just creating another variable that refers to the same `LinkedList` object. Variables in Java (of non-primitive types) are *references*, not objects themselves.

Comment: Please provide your code with Node n=this.head

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand why this toStringLL() changes my head of linked list,when I am iterating through it with l.head=l.head.next?Shouldn't my head stay the same?

When you make the assignment

```
LinkedList l = this;
```

you are not creating a new `LinkedList` object. You are just defining a references to the existing `LinkedList` object.

Therefore, `l.head = l.head.next` does exactly the same as `this.head = this.head.next`. Both change your original list.

On the other hand, when you write

```
Node n = this.head
```

you are not changing the head of your List. You are declaring a variable that initially refers to the `head` of your List, but when you change that variable to refer to other Nodes of your list, the `head` variable of your list (`this.head`) remains unchanged.

Comment: Is it clear for you how OP iterates through the list, using Node n = this.head? I mean he says it works. But differenrce depends on how he uses it further.

Comment: @Russiancold I assumed OP uses `n = n.next;` to iterate over the nodes when using `Node n = this.head`

Answer (score 0):

When you set

```
l.head=l.head.next;
```

you change your head.